# Why is my 2D range not being replaced by a 3D range when using repeat_formula in Perl's Spreadsheet::WriteExcel module?

Tags: perl, excel

I need to create a dynamic Excel formula through a Perl script.

I store a formula that contains a fake range

```
my $stored_formula = $worksheet->store_formula('=MEDIAN(A1:A2)');
```

In the script, I calculate the new range

```
$formula_range = $mm_arr[$mmindx-1] . "!" . 
                 num2col(2+$form_off) . ((($serv-1)*5)+5) . ":" .
                 num2col((2+31+$form_off)) . ((($serv-1)*5)+5);
```

where `@mm_arr` is an array `("Jan", "Feb", &hellip;)`
and `num2col` is a function I use to translate column numbers to letters.

The line just below is the repeat_formula

```
$worksheet->repeat_formula(
     (($serv-1)*5)+4, 
     1+$mmindx, 
     $stored_formula, 
     undef, 
     'A1:A2', $formula_range
);
```

I expect to get:

```
=median(Feb!K3:AH3)
```

but instead I get:

```
=median(K3:AH3)
```

So the find/replace is somehow working, but I can't really pin down how!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `((($serv-1)*5)+5)` is the same as `($serv * 5)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a few recommendations:

There are way too many parentheses in your expressions which, coupled with the variables and functions whose definitions we can't see make your code hard to parse visually. You also did not post a small, self-contained script that exhibits the problem, which means anyone who tries to help you has to set up a test script. Make it easy on others.

For example, the line where you define `$formula_range` can be re-written as follows:

```
my $formula_range = sprintf('%s!%s%d:%s%d',
    $mm_arr[$mmindx - 1],
    num2col(2 + $form_off),
    5 + 5 * ($serv - 1),
    num2col(2 + 31 + $form_off),
    5 + 5 * ($serv - 1),
);
```

Keep in mind you can use functions provided by [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Utility](https://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Utility) to convert between cell notation and row/column indexes.

The problem seems to be that if the stored formula is not in the form `SheetName!Range`, then the substitution chops off the sheet name in the replacement, and only puts in the range.

The reason for this seems to have to do with the parser setup in `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Formula`. A plain range is parsed as a `range2d` token whereas a range with a sheet reference is parsed as a `range3d` token. Later, in `repeat_formula`, the replacement is done on tokens. From what I can gather, a `range2d` token looks like `'_ref2dA1:A10'`. So, `'_ref2dA1:A2'` gets transformed into `'_ref2dFeb!A1:10'` in repeat formula. However, when it is passed to `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Formula::parse_tokens`, the code still classifies it as a `range2d` token based on the prefix. I gather the final call `$parse_str .= $self->_convert_ref2d($token, $class);` then turns it back into `'_ref2dA1:A10`. I am not sure if this could be classified as a bug, but it is definitely unexpected from the user's POV.

So, the solution is to put in the name of a sheet that is guaranteed to exist.

Here is a test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use Const::Fast;

const my @MONTHS => qw(Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec);
const my $WORKBOOK => 'test.xls';

my $book = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($WORKBOOK)
    or die "Cannot open '$WORKBOOK': $!";

my %sheets = map {$_ => $book->add_worksheet($_)} Summary => @MONTHS;

for my $m (@MONTHS) {
    for my $n (1 .. 10) {
        $sheets{ $m }->write_number($n - 1, 0, $n);
    }
}

my $formula = $sheets{Summary}->store_formula('=MEDIAN(Summary!A1:A2)');

for my $n (0 .. 1) {
    my $replacement = sprintf(q{'%s'!A1:A10}, $MONTHS[$n]);

    $sheets{Summary}->repeat_formula($n, 0, $formula, undef,
        'Summary!A1:A2' => $replacement
    );
}

$book->close
    or die "Error closing '$WORKBOOK': $!";
```

And here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot showing correct formulas]

Comment: Adding the Sheetname to the stored formula did the trick. Now it works like a charm. Thanks a lot everybody

Answer (score 1):

The `store_formula()/repeat_formula()` methods are a historical workaround for slow formula parsing use Parse::RecDescent. They are only intended for replacing simple and similar ranges.

Changing the expression from a 2D range to a 3D range isn't going to work since the parsed binary structure that represents each of these formulas is very different and can't be changed with a simple substitution.

You could workaround this in [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/) but instead I would recommend that you use [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Excel-Writer-XLSX/) which is an API compatible replacement for Spreadsheet::WriteExcel, and which doesn't require `store_formula()/repeat_formula()` to speed up repeated formulas.

As a final note, both Excel writer modules come with [::Utility](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Utility.pm) modules for range generation.